# How can I extract specific tokens from a formatted string / CLI output?

Tags: php, regex

I have an array of strings where *"columns"* are divided by spaces:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => 911         (info)    YES   NO   D  1236     UNKNOWN    
    [1] => 910         (no i)    YES   NO   D  1236        NOTE    
    [2] => 909         (no i)    YES   NO   D  1236     UNKNOWN    
    [3] => 742         (info)    YES   NO   D  1236        NOTE    
    [4] => 741/741     (info)    YES   NO   D  1236        NOTE    
    [5] => 740/740     (info)    YES   NO   D  1236     UNKNOWN    
    [6] => john        (no i)    YES   NO   D  0           NOTE    
)
```

I'd like to print only the first item from each line where the line has **NOTE** at the end, ***i.e.***

```
910
742
741       // note that the first token is 741/741 in this case
john
```

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: You made a table by diving the values with spaces?!? Have you ever heard of Object Orientated programming or multidimensional arrays?

Comment: This is just an example output of some other application. Values may be different.

Comment: How are you arriving at the output ?

Comment: So you can only get an array of strings?

Comment: Output might be just text, not an element of an array.

Comment: This is what I have and I coudn't change it.

Comment: Why are you not using multidimensional arrays for this?? that's horrible way to use arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
preg_match_all('/^\w+(?=.*NOTE)/m', implode("\n", $array), $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

[**: demo**](http://ideone.com/fnhD1Z)

***Regex Explanation:***
[image: Regex Visualisation]

`/` regex delimiter

`^` assert position at start of a line

`\w+` match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

- *Quantifier:* Between **one** and unlimited times, as many times as possible, 
  giving back as needed [greedy]

`(?=.*NOTE)` Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched

- `.*` matches any character (except newline)

  - *Quantifier:* Between **zero** and unlimited times, as many times as possible, 
    giving back as needed [greedy]
  - `NOTE` matches the characters *NOTE* literally (case sensitive)

`/`

`m` modifier: multi-line.

- Causes `^` and `$` to match the begin/end of each line 
  (not only begin/end of string)

Comment: @Driver sorry - I never noticed in your example you have spaces at the end of your lines too - I've removed the `$` in my regex example so it should match now.

Comment: This solution seems to be the most convenient. :)
But one thing, how can I change my array from:
Array([0] => line1 [1] => line2) to $array = array('line1', 'line2');

Comment: @Driver I'm really not sure what you mean - are you referring to the output? `print_r` is simply a debugging tool.  In this instance your new array is `$array = $matches[0];`

Comment: I don't know to prepare my array to look like yours in the input. In your example it look like this: $array = array('line1', 'line2'); In my case it is in a different format: Array([0] => line1 [1] => line2)

Comment: @Driver The *"Array"* in your question looks like a `print_r / var_dump` output of an array right? The keys are implicit - all you should need to do is replace the `$array` variable with the name of your actual variable in your code.  If you are having trouble then I'm not 100% sure what you are looking at - can you post your code to a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or update your question with an actual code snippet so I can see what you mean.

Comment: now I understand. I used print_r for my array. It works now but not with `file_put_contents`, my code is here: http://pastebin.com/nKnCPJLE

Comment: @Driver I had a feeling you were splitting a string to get the array in the first place - this is unnecessary - the regex will take care of line breaks... all you need to do is pass the string straight to the function.  Also `print_r` literally prints the output - it doesn't return anything other than a value to denote success.  As I mentioned before this is simply a debugging tool.  If you just wanted to output the captured values on the their own lines you can use `implode`.  See update: http://pastebin.com/VAt3JQrn

Comment: Good, thank you so much! Now if I want to sort values or append anything before each record I need to use `foreach ($matches as $val)`?

Comment: @Driver You can use [`sort`](http://uk1.php.net/sort) or [`usort`](http://uk1.php.net/usort) - if you wish to define your own sorting algorithm (there are loads of examples of how to use this on here already).  But otherwise yes, you will have to loop through the array if you want to format the output.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider changing your array format. Here, lucky you, the 'columns' you want to print are on the same position and are separated by at least one space. The think I image you can do is testig for NOTE as string position, since the whole value is a string, and print only the first part by explode()

```
<?php
$arr = Array
(
    0 => '911         (info)    YES   NO   D  1236     UNKNOWN  ',  
    1 => '910         (no i)    YES   NO   D  1236        NOTE',   
    2 => '909         (no i)    YES   NO   D  1236     UNKNOWN',   
    3 => '742         (info)    YES   NO   D  1236        NOTE',
    4 => '741/741     (info)    YES   NO   D  1236        NOTE',
    5 => '740/740     (info)    YES   NO   D  1236     UNKNOWN',    
    6 => 'john        (no i)    YES   NO   D  0           NOTE'   
);

foreach ($arr as $val) {
    if(strpos($val, 'NOTE')) {
        $val = explode(' ', $val);
        echo $val[0] . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
910
742
741/741
john
```

or, if you want to use `/` as a delimiter too (it seems you don't need anything after the `/` and the `free space`, you can use multiple delimiters with preg_split (a regex)

```
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    if(strpos($val, 'NOTE')) {
        $val = preg_split("/[\/\ ]+/", $val);
        echo $val[0] . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: OP needs the 3rd row as `741` , not `741/741` :)

Comment: It was not set as a rule :) He showed the example output but does not tell, if he wants the values with `/` to have a rule :P however, one can use regex for this. I added an example with preg_split :) Thank you for the remark

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
<?php
$arr=Array
(
    0 => '911         (info)    YES   NO   D  1236     UNKNOWN',
    1 => '910         (info)    YES   NO   D  1236        NOTE',
    2 => '909         (info)    YES   NO   D  1236     UNKNOWN',
    3 => '742         (info)    YES   NO   D  1236        NOTE',
    4 => '741/741     (info)    YES   NO   D  1236        NOTE',
    5 => '740/740     (info)    YES   NO   D  1236     UNKNOWN',
    6 => 'john        (info)    YES   NO   D  0           NOTE'
);

$new_arr = array();
function processFunc($v)
{
    global $new_arr;
    if(strpos($v,'NOTE')!==false)
    {
        if(strpos($v,'/')!==false)
        {
            $new_arr[]=explode('/',$v)[0];

        }
        else
        {
            $new_arr[]=explode(' ',$v)[0];
        }
    }
}

$some_arr=array_map('processFunc',$arr);
echo $string=implode('<br>',$new_arr);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
910
742
741
john
```

Comment: he wants records that contain `NOTE`, nor first 4 :)